# Trailing spaces when using <textarea>

Tags: php, javascript, html, textarea

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <b>Escalation: 
    </td></b>
    <td>
        <TextArea name='escalation' onKeyDown=\"limitText(this.form.escalation,this.form.countdown,100);\"     
onKeyUp=\"limitText(this.form.escalation,this.form.countdown,100);\">$Text</textarea>You have <input readonly type=\"text\" name=\"countdown\" size=\"3\" value=\"100\"> characters left.
    </td>
</tr>
```

That is  a excerpt of the code im trying to use. Basically I'm trying to fill the text area with a value stored in a php variable, which comes from a SQL database. the Javascript functions limit the amount of text in a block to 100 Chars.

Problem is that it fills whatever space isnt used in the initial value with spaces! I printed the $Text between two quotes so I would know for a fact it doesnt have spaces in the database, which it doesnt. You can also clearly see that I dont have any space at all between the textarea tags so that isnt the issue that I see other posters have.

Any ideas?

Comment: most of the chances are that the problem is in limitText()

Comment: why don't you just trim the value when it is passed to the javascript or being passed around?

Comment: Indeed, if spaces are appearing it is the `limitText()` function that is putting them there - we need to see the javascript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I have seen that behavior before. Check to see if the column that you are reading the value from in the database is of type "CHAR" or type "VARCHAR". It is more efficient to always use fixed-length (CHAR) over variable-length (VARCHAR) field types, so databases are sometimes designed that way. The down side is that shorter data stored in those fields is always padded with spaces.

The solution: You probably have a line in your PHP that looks something like this:

```
$Text = $row['text'];
```

Change that line to the following:

```
$Text = trim($row['text']);
```

The 'trim' function will strip leading and trailing spaces. If you are using fixed length fields, remember that you will HAVE TO pad the values that you write to the database as  well. That means that you will have to add leading spaces to the string to be written to the database to make the then proper length for fixed-width field.

Comment: S of a B! That was it! Thanks! In regards to writing it back to the DB: Whenever I've written to the database before, i've never had to do this though.. Why will I need to pad them? its varchar

Comment: You need to pad the values because the field types in the database are CHAR, not VARCHAR. If you have a field that is type VARCHAR(5) then it can contain up to 5 characters. If you have a field type of CHAR(5) then it MUST be exactly 5 characters. So, while a VARCHAR field could be assigned a value of 'car', a CHAR(5) field would have to have a  value of '  car'.

So then why would anybody use a fixed CHAR field type, rather than VARCHAR? Very simple. If ALL of your fields are fixed size, the records are all fixed length, and it's more efficient. But variable length is easier to use.

Comment: Ahhh, if the field IS a VARCHAR, the values may have been stored with leading spaces. You should always TRIM strings before you write them to the DB.